# Efeito scroll elástico em aplicações mobile

Tags: javascript, css, html5, mobile

Gostaria de saber como fazer um efeito hoje muito usado em aplicações mobile, no qual você move os objetos com o dedo "elasticamente" na horizontal ou na vertical, levando algumas vezes os objetos para fora dos limites screen, e logo ele retorna para a posição de origem, em movimentos automatico!

Como acontece no facebook, instagram, twiter...

No Facebook(aplicativos iOS) >>> Feeds: Quando você rola os feeds para baixo com o dedo alcançando o topo da coluna e força alem do limite, alem do efeito elástico, ele faz um refresh das informações atuais dos feeds!

Comment: Nem ideia... Procurei em sites mas não achei nada parecido... Uma vez que é um conteúdo alvo em aplicações mobile, e recente, se torna difícil encontrar algo relativo! Queria entender se funciona apenas em aplicações mobile ou se serve para web sites também, e uma ideia de como funciona! Estou aprendendo ainda efeitos com css e javascript

Comment: e outro fato é que serve para qualquer objeto html... vejo em objetos únicos como um image ou button, e até mesmo em divs inteiras com o caso do facebook!